# SQLite View utilising calculation that ignores data values

Tags: database, sqlite, view, sum, derived

Good Afternoon Everyone,

Utiliisng the code located below, I create a view that will be used to calculate the average time per mile.

```
CREATE VIEW AverageRunTime AS
SELECT UserDetails.username AS username,
CardiovascularRecords.distance_in_miles AS distance,
CardiovascularRecords.start_time AS starttime,
CardiovascularRecords.end_time AS endtime,
sum(strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time) / distance_in_miles) AS averagespeedpermile
FROM UserDetails INNER JOIN CardiovascularRecords
ON Userdetails.username=CardiovascularRecords.username
```

The Issue I am encountering pretains to the distance variable taken into account, with the REAL datatype being utilised I have several decimal values in place such as a range from 0.1 to 1.

When performing the above sum the view will only present data relating to whole numbers ignoring any record containing decimal values entirely.

Any Assistance with this issue would be most welcome, the code relating to my schema is also included below to allow others to replicate my work.

```
CREATE TABLE "CardiovascularRecords" ("record_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE CHECK (record_ID>0) , "distance_in_miles" REAL NOT NULL CHECK (distance_in_miles>0) , "username" TEXT NOT NULL , "date" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, "notes" TEXT(50), "start_time" TEXT, "end_time" TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(distance_in_miles) REFERENCES DistanceinMiles(distance_in_miles) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES UserDetails(username) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

CREATE TABLE "UserDetails" ("username" TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  CHECK (length(username)>0), "password" TEXT NOT NULL  CHECK (length(password)>3), "email_address" TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE CHECK (length(email_address)>3) , "weight_in_pounds" REAL NOT NULL CHECK(weight_in_pounds>0) CHECK (length(weight_in_pounds)>0), "height_in_inches" REAL NOT NULL CHECK(height_in_inches>0) CHECK (length(height_in_inches)>0), "age" INTEGER CHECK(age>0), WITHOUT ROWID)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the code that writes `distance_in_miles` to the database.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "DistanceinMiles" ("distance_in_miles" REAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (null) CHECK (distance_in_miles>0),"distance_in_miles_description" TEXT)

Comment: I meant, show the code *in your program* that writes the `distance_in_miles` values into the `CardiovascularRecords` table.

Comment: There is no program, Im just utilising the database itself, the program used is SQLite manager for manipulation

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(distance_in_miles) FROM CardiovascularRecords`?

Comment: There is no such output, the database holds records containing the distance_in_miles information, this is then used just in views

Comment: But you are using these values in the query.

Comment: Why do you have `sum` in the query? Which records should be summed?

Comment: Having just removed that has corrected my error, Thank you for all your hard work and assistance with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so it is possible to insert strings into the `distance_in_miles` column.

The check `distance_in_miles>0` does not help because [any string compares larger than any number](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons).

Fix your program to store the values as numbers.

Comment: If i store them as whole integers though it wont be an accurate system, some people will only run 0.1 miles etc

Comment: I should also note that the results from the view have ignored anyone with a record below "1" anyone with a decimal has been ommited from the view

Comment: I did not say "whole integers" but "numbers". Your problem is that you are using strings.

Comment: I was led to be informed that REAL was the ideal choice for displaying decimal point values, which is what has been utilised.

Comment: No, you are writing string values.

Comment: what Datatype would you recommend then?

Comment: A number. (Please note that I'm not talking about the column's declared data type but about the data type you are writing.)

Comment: 0.1, as an entered value, is number, or are you refering to the output of the view calculation itself? otherwise ill be honest I am not sure as to which data value you are refering, Distance_in_Miles is a foreign key and is bound to only be able to use values from the distance_in_miles table which consist of values the range 0.1 to 1 nothing more nothing less